# Safest way to remove unwanted whitespace

Tags: javascript, regex, whitespace

I have this HTML string which often has a lot of whitespaces

Example:

```
<p>All     these words <br />
<strong>All</strong>   <em>these</em>   words
<pre>    All    these words</pre>
</p>
```

I need to remove them using JavaScript, and have come up with this regEx:

```
String.replace(/ {2,}/g, '');
```

Which seems to do the job with replacing unwanted whitespaces, but I want to preserve the whitespaces inside the PRE element.

Is this possible with a regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
String.replace(/(<pre[\s\S]*?>[\s\S]*?<\/pre>)| {2,}/ig, '$1')
```

tested in firefox 3

edit:

see test page here: http://ashita.org/StackOverflow/replacetest.html

Comment: Thanks! Seems to work, expect that expected spaces between words is colapsed. Using '$1 ' seems to fix it somehow.

Comment: And we may use <pre.*?> in case the PRE element has any attributes

Comment: it works by first trying to match the pre, then matching the spaces. The pre is inside a capture group (the parentheses). when the pre section is caught, the $1 ensures it is replaced by itself. when 2 consecutive spaces are found, the $1 inserts nothing as the capture group would be empty in this case.

Comment: The following removes new lines and tabs as well: `String.replace(/(<pre[\s\S]*?>[\s\S]*?<\/pre>)|[ \t]{2,}|\n/g, '$1');`  Is this going to cause damage to a valid HTML5 document?

Answer (score 6):

You can't do this with regular expressions and it's as simple as that.

Regular expressions are a poor choice for this kind of thing. `<pre>` blocks can contain other tags and so forth. Also what about CSS (either inline or with classes) that uses the `white-space: pre` property?

HTML and browsers handle white-space just fine. Is this really a problem you need to solve? If you do, you need an HTML parser of some kind.

Comment: While you make a good point cletus, the question was not about elements with white-space:pre. It also didn't ask for elements inside the pre to be treated differently than the pre

Comment: Yes it did.  Inside the pre, the whitespace should not be removed, in contrast to outside.

Comment: @svante: who are you disagreeing with?